# Background process for sending data to server

Tags: ios

Is it possible to run a background task on iOS that uploads data to a server every minute or so, like a service on Android?

Comment: Do you mean in the background like a separate thread or when the app is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like Android. Only when the app is running in the foreground.

Comment: So basically its no possible?

Comment: Impossible unless you jailbreak or run a VOIP app.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like a service but there are certain categories of apps that can be run in the background for an extended period- In addition to VOIP that @lorean mentioned, there are others- audio, location, newsstand , external accessory -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html
. So if your app fits into these categories, then you are set.

Otherwise, you could also run your app as a background audio app by playing silent audio in a loop in the background- but there may be issues trying to get it through the App Store. For instance, you may be required to explicitly inform the user that audio will be played.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it as service except some special cases provided by ios. But you can simulate it. This post answer how to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19121250/2835520

I hope it's gonna help!